# Узнать количество директорий в данной

Tags: python-3.x

Есть какая-то папка и нужно узнать имена её подпапок. Например:

У нас есть такая ситуация

```
test
  folder1
    subfolder
      file1.txt
  folder2
    file2.png
```

Вывод должен быть такой:

[folder1,folder2]

Пробовал через os.walk, может я туповат, но как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте:

```
dirs = next(os.walk('.'))[1]
print(dirs)
```